# IIs rewrite rules only works in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, umbraco

I've trying to redirect the addresses for some old sites using iis rewrite rules.
It works fine in localhost but when I publish my site to Azure and test the url I'll get my 404 error page instead of getting redirected.

This is my web.config:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules configSource="IISRewriteRules.config" />
    </rewrite>
```

My iisRewriteRules.config:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Test redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^company/test" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mypage.com/otherpage" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: in the 404 error are you getting the new URL or the old one. try adding the config inline!

Comment: The rule seems feasible . I want to know if the url in the browser changes when you see the 404 error. If url doesn’t change, it means that redirect didn’t happen and url doesn’t point to the site in Azure. If url changes to other but not www.mypage.com/otherpage, check whether the original URL matches this rule. If the url changes to www.page.com/otherpage correctly, maybe something went wrong with the old site. You can use the url of the old site to visit directly to detect whether it is a problem with the old site.